# How to Merge an Indexed Array into an Unordered Associative Array PHP

Tags: php

I come here for help with an exercise that I have been racking my brain over for 3 hours now. I have two arrays, $authors and $books.

$authors:

```
$authors = array( "Steinbeck", "Kafka", "Tolkien", "Dickens", "Milton", "Orwell" );
```

$books:

```
$books = array(
            array(
                "title" => "The Hobbit",
                "authorId" => 2,
                "pubYear" => 1937
                ),
            array(
                "title" => "The Grapes of Wrath",
                "authorId" => 0,
                "pubYear" => 1939
                ),
            array(
                "title" => "A Tale of Two Cities",
                "authorId" => 3,
                "pubYear" => 1859
                ),
            array(
                "title" => "Paradise Lost",
                "authorId" => 4,
                "pubYear" => 1667
                ),
            array(
                "title" => "Animal Farm",
                "authorId" => 5,
                "pubYear" => 1945
                ),
            array(
                "title" => "The Trial",
                "authorId" => 1,
                "pubYear" => 1925
                ),
        );
```

As you can see, $authors is a two-dimensional indexed array whereas $books is a multidimensional associative array. My task is to create a new key (I think a key? Even the vocabulary for arrays messes me up..) for $books called "authorName", and populate the key with the authors from the $authors array. The catch is that the index for the authors in the $authors array corresponds to the "authorId" in the $books array, however the IDs are out of order.

In other words, my task is to pull the data from the $authors array so that the books array ends up with the following data:

```
$books = array(
            array(
                "title" => "The Hobbit",
                "authorId" => 2,
                "pubYear" => 1937
                "authorName" => "Tolkien"
                ),
            array(
                "title" => "The Grapes of Wrath",
                "authorId" => 0,
                "pubYear" => 1939
                "authorName" => "Steinbeck"
                ),
            array(
                "title" => "A Tale of Two Cities",
                "authorId" => 3,
                "pubYear" => 1859
                "authorName" => "Dickens"
                ),
```

...and so on. Any help would be appreciated since I have absolutely no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Congrats on learning PHP! I'll start with the minor things like vocabulary; I think it's important in programming to get it right ;-)

1. The `$authors` array is not two-dimensional
2. You said it was out of order, but I don't think it is. Keep in mind array indexes are 0-based.
3. Yes, "key" is an okay way to describe what you are trying to add. Slightly more semantically appropriate might be "entry", where "entry" is comprised of a "key" and it's "value"

Here is some code. I've chosen to be slightly more verbose than I might usually author code in order to be clear what is happening.

```
foreach($books as $book_index => $book_array) {
    // Get the index of the author in the $authors array.
    // With this value, $authors[$authorId] will be the name of the author of this book
    $authorId = intval($book_array['authorId']);

    // this line adds an entry to the current book in the $books array.
    $books[$book_index]['authorName'] = $authors[$authorId];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation and corrections, the code works exactly as it should and I can see how it does through the comments. Much appreciated!

Comment: @NoahMatisoff IMO, no it isn't. There are so many people copy pasting code out there who have no idea **why** something works, they just know it does because the code was provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by simply running a loop on `$books` as followed.

```
foreach($books as $index => $book){
    $books[$index]['authorName'] = $authors[$book['authorId']];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below snippet should do the trick.  Iterate over the books array, set `authorName` equal to the value correspondent to the iteration's book `authorId`.

```
foreach($books as $key => $book) {
    $books[$key]['authorName'] = $authors[$book['authorId']];
}
```